# How does Google Sheets override browser shortcuts?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-sheets, keyboard-shortcuts

I'm creating a complicated in-browser app and I'd like to use some keyboard shortcuts that are currently used by Chrome and/or the other major browsers.  I searched online and couldn't find a way to override browser shortcuts, but I saw that Google Sheets has just the kind of functionality I want: a user can select an option to override browser shortcuts.

How does Google sheets make this work?

Update: To clarify, since this has gotten some downvotes:  I'm aware of event.preventDefault().  The problem is that it does not seem to work for key combinations like `Ctrl + t` (open new tab).

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The general idea is to intercept the event and call `event.preventDefault()` on it if it corresponds to a shortcut that you want to override. For example, the following code will prevent you from navigating to your leftmost tab if you press `control-1`:

```js
document.body.addEventListener('keydown', (event) => {
  // keyCode 49 corresponds to the "1" key
  if(event.keyCode==49 && event.ctrlKey) {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log('default action prevented, doing custom action instead');
  }
});
```

```css
body {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
click me first
```

Repeat for as many keyCodes and modifiers as you want.

Comment: I tried adding your code to my app and while it worked for `Ctrl + 1`, it did not work for `Ctrl + t`.  However I also noticed that Google Sheets does not override `Ctrl + t`, so maybe it's a browser shortcut that cannot be overridden.

Comment: Huh, interesting. So `Ctrl + 1` is, *somehow*, in a different realm from `Ctrl + t`. I wonder why.