# How can i override browser shortcuts, but maintain an internal key press listener?

Tags: angular, typescript

Linked Questions

1. Listen - [How can I listen for keypress event on the whole page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37362488/how-can-i-listen-for-keypress-event-on-the-whole-page)
2. Override - [How does Google Sheets override browser shortcuts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52774572/how-does-google-sheets-override-browser-shortcuts)

I'm trying to create a web page that helps people build Macros for LUAMacros.
part of this is to interpret Key presses within the browser, these may trigger browser shortcuts

```
        <script>
        document.body.addEventListener('keydown', (event) => {
                       event.preventDefault();
        });
    </script>
```

this will prevent the browser from responding to built in shortcuts. however also prevents the angular component listening to the key press

```
@HostListener('document:keypress', ['$event'])
handleKeyboardEvent(event: KeyboardEvent) {
    this.key = event.key;
    console.log(this.key);
    event.preventDefault();
}
```

Without the script, the browser responds to shortcuts, however with it the component will not fire the above host listener.

the components ' event.preventDefault();' appears to respond after the browser recognises the short cut.

Incidentally i'm trying to resolve [CTRL + k] which chrome uses for search.

Comment: In the script conditionally call `event.preventDefault()` based on browser shortcut key combinations so that the HostListener will work for the other events

Comment: My use case is that I'm trying to capture any potential key combination so need to block all shortcuts

Comment: There is package have a look [here](https://wangchujiang.com/hotkeys/)

Answer (score 0):

You can utilize the fact that events bubble up the DOM tree. In your Angular code, listen to events as you already do: by attaching an event listener to `document`. In  the global part of the page, simply listen to `window` instead of `document`.

Every event that happens will firstly be triggered on `document` (allowing you to perform custom action). Unless `Event#stopPropagation` is called on it, it will *then* bubble up to `window` (where you'll catch it and prevent its default behavior, as defined by browser).

```html
<script>
  window.addEventListener('keydown', event => {
    event.preventDefault()
  })
</script>
```

```
@HostListener('document:keypress', ['$event'])
public handleKeyboardEvent (event: Event) {
  event.preventDefault()
}
```

Comment: I can see what you are trying to do here although it appears not to be working. i have added the above snippets and some variants into various combinations of the index.html and the component and the experience is the same as described in the original question. thanks however :)